# How to sanitize PSQL LIKE query against injection attacks - SQALCHEMY PYTHON

Tags: python, sql-like, psql, sanitization

I am trying to sanitize an sql query using python when I pass it some variables that are taken from a form. I have the below:

```
listOfBooks = db.execute("SELECT * from books WHERE " + searchParameter + " LIKE" + "'%"+ ":searchString" +"%'", {"searchString": searchString} ).fetchall()
```

but obviously it gives me an error because it interprets it as

`SELECT * from books WHERE isbn LIKE'%'2017'%'`,

so the problem is that there are extra single quotation marks around 2017 which shouldn't be there.

How to solve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which language do you use, I assume it is Java, in that case you should replace the single quote to double single quota like this

```
searchString.replace("'", "''")
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write I am using python!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the syntax is the same for python as well

Comment: what is the output of the statement interpretation?

Comment: still the same, SELECT * from books WHERE year LIKE'%'2017'%'

Comment: You don't want any quotes in the searchString: searchString.replace("'", "")

Comment: searchString = request.form.get("books")
searchString2 = searchString.replace("'","''")
listOfBooks = db.execute("SELECT * from books WHERE " + searchParameter + " LIKE " + "'%"+ ":searchString2" +"%'", {"searchString2": searchString2} ).fetchall()

Comment: Doesn't make sense, according to your previous reply, the replace didn't worked

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I have also tried to apply the replace that @AndrewLouw suggested, to no avail.

Comment: Guys I found the solution! It didn't work because even if I escaped the single quotes, the program kept adding them later when I passed the dictionary with searchString into the query! so what I did was I added more single quotes directly into the query, like this: listOfBooks = db.execute("SELECT * from books WHERE " + searchParameter + " LIKE " + "'%'"+ ":searchString2" +"'%'", {"searchString2": searchString2} ).fetchall() and it works now!

Comment: but now it always returns an empty array from the database. That's weird!

Comment: ok, last comment, I actually did find a solution now, and it is as follows: searchString = request.form.get("books")
searchString2 = "%"+searchString+"%"
listOfBooks = db.execute("SELECT * from books WHERE " + searchParameter + " LIKE " +  ":searchString2" , {"searchString2": searchString2} ).fetchall()